# How can i filter my google api query by mime-types

Tags: google-drive-api

Using https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list, I want to list the files that stored in my google drive using query by mime-type.

example GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files by mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'

Based on this website https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files Where can I find this option?

looking for your suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint you are looking for is this? This endpoint retrieves Spreadsheet files in Google Drive as a list.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

#### Note :

- When you use this, please do URL encode as follows.

  - GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType%3D'application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

#### Reference :

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/query-ref)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want. but just for more information why you add q=mimeType ?

Comment: @MokiNex Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. For the information of ``q``, you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) and [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/query-ref).